# In python doit how to run task only when some condition is met

Tags: python, doit

Something really simple I want to achieve with python doit module.
I have task_entry and three other tasks: task_a, task_b, task_c.
I want to control from task_entry which of the either tasks a, b, or c
to get evaluated.
Lets say there is a config file from which task entry finds out which
among a, b, c to execute.
I am not able to express this simple requirement in doit framework.
file_dep only controls the order of execution and not if a task is selected at all. Below is the MWE:

```
# dodo.py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

def choose_task():
    task_to_run = config.get("config", "task_to_run")
    return {"task_dep": [task_to_run]}

def task_entry():
    return {
        "actions": None,
        "calc_dep": choose_task,
    }

def task_a():
    return {
        "actions": ["echo 'Task A'"],
    }

def task_b():
    return {
        "actions": ["echo 'Task B'"],
    }

def task_c():
    return {
        "actions": ["echo 'Task C'"],
    }
```

Currently all tasks, A, B, and C will run. I will like only the task specified in config file to run.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]

Comment: In the function `task_entry` what is `choose_task`, unless defined this will not run.

Comment: its the task associated with calc_dep. It reads from config file and returns which task to run.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to solve this. Need to use DOIT_CONFIG to define the default_tasks so that only entry task runs. The calc_dep task will make sure that right task gets picked up as part of dependency.